# Is it possible to have more than 3 overloads on My.Computer.Audio.Play VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, audio, arguments

I've got to do an audio background **AND** wait to complete heres my code.

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.music, AudioPlayMode.Background, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

But it doesnt work because: "Overload resolution failed because no accessable 'Play' accepts this number of arguments."

Any way to get more arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option might be to write an asynchronous method that plays the audio in the background.  That way, you can await that method:

```
Private Async Function PlayInBackgroundAsync(data As Stream) As Task
    Await Task.Run(Sub() My.Computer.Audio.Play(data, AudioPlayMode.Background)).ConfigureAwait(False)
End Function
```

Just note that any method that you await a method call must ne declared `Async`, e.g.

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Await PlayInBackgroundAsync(My.Resources.music)
End Sub
```

Using await means that execution won't proceed until the code in the method being executed completes but that the UI won't be blocked either.

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa slow down! I'm just a begginner

Comment: ignore ^^^^^^^ i did what you said but, When I put in My.Resources.music in the brackets it comes up with this error: value of unmanaged memory stream could not be converted to byte() i put inverted commas round it but came up with; cannot convert string to byte(). i changed (data as byte()) to (data as string) but still had the outcome from the start; two sounds can't play at once

Comment: @EarthMonster : For the record, you can delete comments using the little `x` that is shown when hovering over it. As for your issue, in jmcilhinney's code change `data As Byte()` to `data As Stream`.

Comment: Sorry about that error. I was assuming which overload of `Play` you were calling and obviously got it wrong.  As @EarthMonster says, you can change `Byte()` to `Stream` and code will compile.  I've made that change to my answer.  `Stream` is a member of the `System.IO` namespace, so be sure to import that.